# Template argument deduction, Qualified-Id and performance

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

Suppose I have a *lambda* function:

```
std::function<void (int&& y)> lambda = [](int&& y) { std::cout << std::forward<int>(y) << std::endl; };
```

Having another function named *`gate`* which takes the lambda function as arg:

```
template<typename T> void gate(T&& x, std::function<void (T&&)> f) { f(std::move(x)); };
```

as the template argument deduction cannot make equal the types `lambda(0)` and `std::function<void (T&&)>`, Indeed, I specifically need to pass the `std::function<void (T&&)>` directly to through *`gate`* function, a commonly used solution is to make the lambda function parameter as *non-deduced context*. The scope is achieved using some struct which takes in some arbitrary type and spit it right back out. Hence, template argument deduction fails and the type of `'T&&'` is deducted elsewhere, in this case from the first argument passed which type was correctly deducted.

```
template typename<T> struct Identity { typedef T type };

template<typename T> void gate(T&& x, typename Identity<std::function<void (T&&)>>::type f) { f(std::move(x)); };

int main() { gate(1234, [](int&& y) { std::cout << std::forward<int>(y) << std::endl; }); }
```

What I am wondering is, are there some lost in performance given the usage of the 'identity' struct? Could this be made better? Is creating firstly lambda and then pass it as argument the better way?

Comment: Why do you use `std::forward<int>` in that code? You do realize that `i` is always a rvalue reference to `int`? For `int` there's also little reason to use rvalue references or references to const, since `int`s are cheap to copy...

Comment: @fabian, std :: move, std :: forward are left over from previous use of lambda; I left them for no reason. Clearly it is just an example and the two functions are irrelevant to the example. Initially was `std::forward<Args>(args)...`

Comment: `identity` is a compile time thing.  It may increase the time to compile but there will be no run time cost.  std::function<void (T&&)>` OTOH does come with a performance penalty thanks to its usage of type erasure.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just take `f` as-is like `template<typename T, typename F> void gate(T&& x, F&& f) { std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<T>(x)); }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am wondering is, are there some lost in performance given the usage of the 'identity' struct?

Certainly no runtime performance because the structure is never instantiated or used.

Compilation speed could be affected since the compiler has to instantiate that type but it "amortizes" together with the instantiation of the function template itself since there is 1:1 correspondence. It will highly depend on the compiler how quickly it can throw those instantiations away.

FYI there is [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) in C++20 for exactly this purpose which might allow the compiler to improve its performance. Maybe it will get similar treatment how [Clang 15 now treats `std::forward` and others as builtins instead of instantiating them](https://releases.llvm.org/15.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#id5).